# pass char pointer as template parameter to function on header

Tags: c++

i am trying to simulate add/drop courses but i am getting segmentation error.
(adding courses to linked list) , i also tried with char array but problem still occurs.I am not good at c++ , i searched usage of template and every example was like mines but mine is not working...

Header file :

```
template<class T>
class LL
{
protected:
    node<T> *head, *last;
    int count;
public:
    LL();
    ~LL();
    bool emptyList();
    int length(){return count;};
    T back();
    T front();
    void destroyList();
    node<T> *search(T&);
    void insertFirst(T&);
    void insertLast(T&);
    void deleteNode(T&);
    void printList();
        template<class T>
        void LL<T>::insertLast(T& item)
        {
            node<T> *p = new node<T>;
            p->info = item;
            p->link = NULL;
            if(head != NULL)
            {
                last->link = p;
                last = p;
            }else head = last = p;
            count++;
        }
    template<class T>
    node<T> *LL<T>::search(T& item)
    {
        bool found = false;
        node<T> *p = head;
        while((p != NULL) &&  found)
        {
            if(p->info == item)
                found = true;
            else p = p->link;
        }
        return p;
    }
```

Main class

```
 LL<char*> ll;
    while(true)
    {
        char command[256];
        cout << "Enter Add | Drop | Change | List | Quit:";
        cin>>command;
        cout<<endl;

        if(strcmp(command,"Add")==0)
        {
            char* course;
            char* credit;
            char* section;

            cout<<"Enter CourseCode, Credit and Section to be added:"<<endl;
            cin>>course>>credit>>section;
            cout<<course<<" "<<credit<<" "<<section<<endl;

            if(ll.search(course) == NULL)
            {
                ll.insertLast(course);
            }
        }
}`
```

Comment: You really should be using `std::string` for strings.

Comment: What is your `node` implementation? Also note that you could use `std::list`

Comment: @NathanOliver i am trying for 2 hours and string is right answer , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work

```
strcmp(command,"Add")==0
```

because `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );` and `"Add"` is a string. You'd better write smth like

```
std::string str("Add");
char* chr = (char*)str.c_str();
strcmp(command, chr)==0
```

Comment: This is not correct. A string literal like "Add" can be cast to an std::string, but is interpreted first as an r-value `char` array, e.g. `const char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code. The most basic one is that you have not allocated memory for the `char *` pointers written onto via `std::cin`. If memory is allocated via

```
char* course = new char[256];
```

the segfault is fixed. Then, `LL<char*>` can be used as the linked list type -- though it would still be better to use `std::string`.

Additionally, your `LL::search` method is broken, and you need to rethink its logic. Beyond this, you have some more trivial problems that might have arisen from copy-pasting your code into the question box.

Comment: Yeah my search and insert is not good , because i am inserting every property of course together as concanated string ; its like Ceng553 3 1 => this means course code ceng553 , course credit is 3 and section is 1 but this corrupts my search algorithm because i have to search with only course code , it looks like i have to add with string array

Comment: @hkn Well, in the code you showed there is no concatenation, so I'll assume you added this later. The problem I was referring to is that you probably wanted to put `not found` in the while condition rather than `found`.

Comment: yeah put it later , if it is java i probably create a inner class to hold course code , credit , section it looks like i need to do like this , i will create a struct and instert it